# create int[] listbox multiselect

Tags: c#, listbox

I need to get all selected items of a listbox and then insert inside a int[] array.

```
int[] status = new int[] { 0 };                
foreach (ListItem Status in lstFiltro.Items)
{
  if (Status.Selected == true)
  {
    status[] = Convert.ToInt32(Status.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Winforms?  WPF?  Also do you mean you want to put the selected INDEX inside an array?  Or some other value?

Answer (score 1):

With a for-loop you'd want to add items to a list (it'll be easier).  Or you could just do this (assuming you're using .Net 3.5+):

```
using System.Linq;
....
var status = lstFiltro.Items.Where(s => s.Selected)
                            .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Value)
                            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Error 50 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: @soamazing: It is IEnumerable so you should be able to do this.  You may need to add the `using` line I just added.

Comment: @Salonen                 var qry = from ListItem item in lstFiltro.Items
                            select new { item.Selected, Value = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value) };
                status = qry.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();